# Fetch data from external own SQLite database

Tags: android, database, sqlite, null, cursor

I have my own database which contains http://i55.tinypic.com/6i8861.jpg (SQLiteBrowser)
I have this code, which copies the database from the assets resource folder to the system `data/data/package/files` directory http://pastebin.com/XeNGmrcD  and this is how it is implemented into the onCreate() http://pastebin.com/TigXFStF  and this is the image where the test.sqlite is placed into the emulator system dir and the error I get when I execute the query below: http://i51.tinypic.com/2mxrk0p.jpg

```
cursor = dbObj.getReadableDatabase().query(TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
```

I get that cursor is null since there is no table found. If I execute the same query equivalent to the one above (`SELECT * FROM gradovi`) in the SQLite Browser. I get results, here I don't.
Please tell me how can i fetch data from my database? What I'm doing wrong? Also I want to know how to iterate through the records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the database file copying is failing.  Your code has a number of swallowed exceptions, so you might not be seeing the errors that occur.

Note that trying to ship an app with a pre-built SQLite database file is wrought with pitfalls, including varying paths and varying SQLite versions.

Comment: It does copy it, I've exported the file that is created from the code and check it with the SQLite Browser it has the same data it should. Version is 2, also i keep the path static. I'm just working on changing names of the dbs (that should take place) based on the cases. Anyways I've managed to fix this myself. Now it works flawlessly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.button01)).setOnClickListener(
new View.OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatabaseHelper myDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(CopyDbActivity.this);
        try{
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        }catch (IOException ioe) {
            throw new Error("Unable to create database");
        }

        try {                
            myDbHelper.openDataBase();
        }catch(SQLException sqle){
            throw sqle;
        }

        Toast.makeText(CopyDbActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        c=myDbHelper.query("EMP_TABLE", null, null, null, null,null, null);
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            do {
                Toast.makeText(CopyDbActivity.this,
                "_id: " + c.getString(0) + "\n" +
                "E_NAME: " + c.getString(1) + "\n" +
                "E_AGE: " + c.getString(2) + "\n" +
                "E_DEPT:  " + c.getString(3),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } while (c.moveToNext());
        }
    }
});



}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's my understanding that the destination should be "/data/data/PackageName/databases/mydatabase".

You might also get some help from http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/